# Return SOAP fault object with custom faultcode and message in Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have a Spring webservice which throws a custom exception for any error scenerio. I have configured the exception class like this:

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.CUSTOM, customFaultCode="{http://com/examples/webservice/utils/AppConstants}"+AppConstants.FAULT_CODE)
public class ConfigurationException extends Exception {/**Codes**/}
```

Throwing exception as below:

```
throw new ConfigurationException("Validation exception");
```

and in Spring config xml I have added this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver"/>
```

It is working fine if I call this service from SOAPUI. I'm getting proper SOAP fault with *faultcode* and *faultString*.

But, when I'm invoking the service from java spring client. I'm getting SOAP fault as exception.My requirement is to get SOAP fault message object so that I can get the *faultCode* and *faultString*.

Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the fault in the client code, and in the catch block retrieve the fault code and string with exception.getFaultCode() and exception.getFaultString(), have a look at the j[avadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html) for further details.